# Distance between two points in a solid of revolution

Tags: differential-geometry, solid-of-revolution

> Let $f: I \to (0,\infty)$ be a smooth and positive function. Let
>   $$\Sigma_f = \{(x,f(x)\cos\theta,f(x)\sin\theta) : x \in I, \theta \in \Bbb{R}\}$$
>   be a solid of revolution generated by rotating the graph of $f$ around the $x$-axis. Determine the distance between $(x,f(x),0)$ and $(y,f(y),0)$.

I don't know how to approach this problem. My definition of distance is taken over all curves $C^1$ by parts (the infimum of these lengths). Maybe I must minimize the arch length between these points. But how to ensure that the arch will be contained in $\Sigma_f$?

Comment: Do you know anything about geodesics on a surface of revolution?

Comment: You may want to check Clairaut's relation on Wikipedia. It is a simple condition describing geodesics on surfaces of revolution.

Comment: @TedShifrin I know just basic definition. But I can read more if this is the only way to attempt this problem

Answer (score 1):

Note that both those points are on a single copy of the curve that you're rotating around. Any one of those copies is itself a geodesic, as you can check by looking at the acceleration vector if you travel along the curve with constant speed.